# How do you cite an entry in an online reference work using BibLaTeX apa?

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to cite an entry from Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy using the BibLaTeX apa package. The APA manual specifies that you should cite an online entry in the following way:

> Graham, G. (2005) Behaviorism. In E. N. Zalta (Ed.), *The Stanford
>   encyclopedia of philosophy* (Fall 2007 ed.). Retreived from
>   http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/behaviorism/

I've been experimenting with different entry types. The closest I've found something that works is by using the `@inbook` entry which gives me everything exept the "(Fall 2007 ed.)" part. The closest I manage to get is by filling in something in the Edition-field, which only accepts numbers, getting an output looking like this:

> Graham, G. (2005) Behaviorism. In E. N. Zalta (Ed.), *The Stanford
>   encyclopedia of philosophy* (2007th ed.). Retreived from
>   http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/behaviorism/

Note: I *could* circumvent this whole problem by simply putting all the text in the title-field, then using emphasis commands to stylize everything correctly. That does, however, feel a little bit like cheating and I would prefer not to mess up my .bib-file in this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting from the `biblatex` manual, section 2.2.2 (empasis added):

> edition -- field (integer or literal)
>
> The edition of a printed publication. This must be an integer, not an
>   ordinal. Don’t say `edition={First}` or `edition={1st}` but
>   `edition={1}`. The bibliography style converts this to a language
>   dependent ordinal. *It is also possible to give the edition as a
>   literal string, for example “Third, revised and expanded edition”.*

This also seems to work with `biblatex-apa`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Gra05,
  author = {Graham, G.},
  year = {2005},
  title = {Behaviorism},
  booktitle = {The Stanford encyclopedia of philosophy},
  editor = {Zalta, E. N.},
  edition = {Fall 2007 ed.},
  url = {http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/behaviorism/},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the examples in the "biblatex-apa-test-references.bib" file that comes with the APA style for BibLaTeX - search that file for "APA 7.02 Example 29" (These ID strings in the .bib test files refer to the APA 6th edition section and example numbers so you can find them easily). It's also to be found in the compiled PDF "biblatex-apa-test.pdf" which comes with the style. This test file typesets most of the examples in the APA guide and the commented .bib files show you the .bib entries.