# Appropriate biblatex entry type for part of an online-only reference

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing

I'd like to `\cite` an entry in a scholarly handbook, albeit one that is not available in printed form but rather only on the WWW.

If this were part of a larger reference work but not online, `@InReference`'d be the entry type of choice (more generally, `@InCollection` or `@InBook`); and if it were online but not part of a larger work, `@Online` (or its alias `@WWW`). But what's right if it's both part of a larger work *and* online?

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503036/158639) from about three years ago where David Purton, in a comment, suggested `@InBook`. That's basically what I'm using myself: `@InReference` with `howpublished = {online}`, which is working alright. Nonetheless I'm wondering --- is this still the state of the art/best current practice?

(FWIW the biblatex documentation itself does not explicitly state that the `collection` types are intended only for printed collections, but the reference to volumes makes it fairly obvious IMO that they are.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a requirement that an `@inreference` (or indeed a `@book`, `@inbook`, `@collection`, `@incollection`, `@reference`, ...) be a printed (not online-only) work. If there is wording that implies this in the `biblatex` documentation I'd put that down to the data model being inspired ultimately by the data model of the BibTeX base styles which were written at a time when online-only publications of such works was not common (to say the least).

So if semantically (apart from the publication method: online vs print) `@inreference` seems the best fit, go for it.

The [*Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy*](https://plato.stanford.edu/) is a good example of a work that works perfectly as `@(in)collection`/`@(in)reference` even though it is online only. See for example [How do you cite an entry in an online reference work using BibLaTeX apa?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33324/35864) and [How to include the title of the website in bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172441/35864).